# Shortcut trick for solving probabilities

Tags: probability, intuition

This question is a follow up from this [answer + comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3094006/625055) which I am really in love with.

Following Steve's suggestion from the comments I decided to try it, even though at first I didn't believe that it can be the correct way.

Suppose that we have an urn with $5$ white balls and $7$ black balls. What is the probability that on the third extraction we get a black ball?

The first and the standard way that I've learn to this is by using Total Probability law.

I will denote $3$b as the third ball to be black, $2w=$ second ball to be white and so on.

$$P(3b)=P(3b,2b,1b)+P(3b,2b,1w)+P(3b,2w,1b)+P(3b,2w,1w)$$
$$=\frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{11}\cdot \frac{5}{10}+\frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{11}\cdot\frac{6}{10}+\frac{7}{12}\cdot\frac{5}{11}\cdot\frac{6}{10}+\frac{5}{12}\cdot\frac{4}{11}\cdot \frac{7}{10}$$
$$=\frac{210+210+210+140}{12\cdot 11\cdot 10}=\frac{3\cdot21+14}{132}=\frac{77}{132}$$

But the probability of drawing the black ball first is actually: $$P(1b)=\frac{7}{12}=\frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{11}{11}=\frac{77}{132}$$

Which is equal to the result found the hard way.
Why does this phenomen happen? I can see that numerically it works, but I can't find an intuition behind it.

Does this *shortcut trick* have a name? In my school I never encountered this type of solving probabilities.
Also could you suggest me some more tricks like this?

Comment: The ball doesn't know whether it's the first extraction, the third, or the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you extract all of the balls and line them up.

The probability that the third ball will be black will be the same in this situation, as it will for when we stop after drawing it.

**Now, every *individual ball* will have an equal probability for being the third ball as for being the first ball.**

Seven of the twelve balls are black.

So the probability that the third ball will be black is $7/12$.

Comment: Woah, this makes perfect sense! Thank you. Indeed to line them up is a beautiful explanation.

Comment: If it's possible, can you tell me also why here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093956/probability-of-extracting-a-ball-after-two-balls-were-swapped/3094006#3094006 the order doesn't matter?

Comment: I agree that thinking of lining up the balls is the right way to explain this!

Answer (score 0):

It is just due to the fact that the fact you already drew two balls doesn't matter because you didn't look at them.  You can imagine drawing three balls, then only looking at the third.  How is it different from drawing one and looking at it?  So the chance it will be black is the same for the third ball as the first.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help me, why looking at the balls would change anything?/// "You can imagine drawing three balls, then only looking at the third. How is it different from drawing one and looking at it?". Well, two more balls are touched in the first case, right?

Comment: You can look at them as long as you don't do anything with the information.  If you ask things like what is the chance the third is black given that the first is black it will change the probability.

Comment: Oh, so here the draws are actually independent from the other?

Comment: They are not independent because if you draw black first the chance you will draw black on the third is lower.  If you average over all the first draws the chance on the third is the same as the chance on the first.

Comment: Oops, I miss thought that, thank you! // Would you mind taking a look at this answer too https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3094006/625055 ? Is there a connection between those two? (Now I  fail to understand why there the order doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an example that *might* help illuminate the idea in my answer to the other question. It’s somewhat convoluted, but maybe it’s fun to think about even if it doesn’t help.

Suppose an urn contains $10$ white balls and $11$ black balls. You draw a ball from the urn, but unbeknownst to you, someone has previously chosen one of the urn’s $21$ balls at random and cast a magic spell called $S(12,13)$ on it. The spell *may* cause the ball to change color one week after it’s removed.

Specifically, the spell $(12,13)$ causes a ball to end up white after one week with probability $12+r\over12+13+1$, where $r=0$ if the ball is initially black and $r=1$ if the ball is initially white. (It’s a weird spell, but if you read the question that began this discussion, you may see where I’m going with it.)

What is the probability $p$ that the ball you draw will be white a week after you draw it?

Clearly, the probability that the ball is white *when* you draw it is $10\over21$, because the spell does nothing, and $10$ of the urn’s $21$ balls are white.

Denote by $M$ the event that you drew a magic ball, and denote by $W$ the event that you draw an initially-white ball. These are independent events, since the spell and your draw each target a random ball.

By the law of total probability, $p=P(M')P(W) + P(M)x$, where $x$ is the probability that a magic ball drawn from an urn with $10$ white and $11$ black balls will be white in a week.

What is $x$? If *black* magic balls are white in a week with probability $12+0\over26$ and *white* magic balls are white in a week with probability $12+1\over26$, then a ball drawn from an $10$-white-and-$11$-black distribution is white in a week with probability $12+{10\over21}\over26$.

Thus $p = P(M')P(W) + P(M)x={20\over21}\cdot{10\over21}+{1\over21}\cdot{12+{10\over21}\over26}={2731\over5733}\approx 0.4763649$.